# How to enable selection one by one by using JSON response?

Tags: html, angularjs, json

I am new to angularjs and I want to select values one by one. Before that

I have a below JSON response.

```
[
  {
    "countryname": "India",
    "states": [
      {
        "statename": "Karnataka",
        "cities": [
          {
            "city": "Bangalore",
            "segments": [
              {
                "segments": "one"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

From this I need to display only country in country tag as a select list, state in state list and so on.

Before selecting country everything other select option like state, city segment should be disabled.

It has to be enabled one by one.

Comment: I'm seeing quite a few of your questions featuring begging, e.g. "please help me", "it's urgent", etc. Please don't add this fluff - the volunteers here will get around to questions they like the look of at their leisure.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you want, but I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vewsujue/4/) demonstrating how to create select lists based on your JSON response.

HTML

```
<select ng-model="selectedCntry" ng-options="cntry.countryname for cntry in countries"></select>
<select ng-model="selectedState" ng-options="state.statename for state in stateOpts"></select>
<select ng-model="selectedCity" ng-options="city.city for city in cityOpts"></select>
```

Controller

```
$scope.selectedCntry = $scope.countries[0];
$scope.stateOpts = $scope.selectedCntry.states;
$scope.selectedState = $scope.stateOpts[0];
$scope.cityOpts = $scope.selectedState.cities;
$scope.selectedCity = $scope.cityOpts[0];
```

Note that this example does not handle disabling of state and city when country is not selected.